# Simplex, half-duplex, full-duplex (ccent1)

Tags: networking, cisco

If simplex, half and full duplex are OSI layer 5 (session layer) modes, why are they configurable on a l2 switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Medium directionality (L2) and protocol directionality (L5) are independent concepts.

I've never seen a L2 switch that included "simplex" in the port configuration, though such a configuration might be possible with security settings. Half and full duplex are only applicable to 10 and 100 Mb connections. 1 and 10GbE are natively full duplex.

Comment: Why don't I see these specifics in any documentation? I want to cry.

Comment: How can I identify what they are talking about in exam questions? What layer does full-duplex and half-duplex belong? Seems ambiguous.

Comment: No idea what documentation you're looking at, or what would have the specifics you're looking for. In the CCENT I would assume if they're talking about duplex it's in relation to a port, that test isn't terribly complicated. Have you worked in IT for a while?? The Cisco tests really aren't meant for complete beginners.